Align certain faces in a mesh to an absolute angle along a local axis
I have a large complex mesh, a landscape with a road. When I created this I took steps to keep the faces that make up the road flat but after some adjustments many of them are no longer straight. that is the road is "tilted" to the side. I need to find a way to fix this. I can easily select the faces because they have a unique material, but there are thousands of them among many thousands of other faces in the landscape, so manually fixing each one isn't really feasible. is there a way I can select those faces, and rotate them all individually so they are at 0 degrees on the 'local y' axis? that is the axis that goes from one side of the road to the other, while not actually moving those faces nor altering their angle along the local X or local Z axis?

I hope this maybe helps to explain, so I think the "road" was flat originally but topology changed as I was doing other work. the dark gray faces are a road in a landscape, the cube is aligned with that road but is at a perfect 0 degrees, so its top and bottom faces are "flat" as you can see the road is quite tilted here after some other work and not paying close enough attention with proportional editing. the road goes up and down hills and turns around corners, that needs to stay just as it is, but I need to "tilt" the road back to being level. so far the best way I have found to do this is to use proportional editing and eyeball it rotating one face at a time then going to the next section until it looks good enough. but this landscape is rather large, there are too many faces to just fix each one manually.
I know I could make a face perfectly flat by selecting the "left" and "right" edges in edge select mode then scale on Z and type in 0. that should do it for one face, but there must be a better way to do this for the whole thing, I do have a unique material and a vertex group of just the road so I Can select the faces I need easily. is there a way I can "copy" the rotation of one face in that one axis only (when I rotate it manually its the Y axis in this particular case) and paste that rotation to all other faces in that group or with that material?
or a way to select those faces and rotate the normal to be straight up, but only in one axis so it levels the road but doesn't flatten the hills?
I still have a lot to learn, but I just keep thinking there must be some smarter way to do this. Thanks for any and all help.

It would be helpful if you posted some screenshots demonstrating what you're trying to accomplish. It's hard to figure it out by just reading you describing it. Also can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Thanks for the reply! The blend file is very large, bu;t I will see if I can post some screenshots that can illustrate the issue and what I'm trying to fix.

Try putting only the elements you're having an issue with into a separate file. Blender allows Ctrl+C -> Ctrl+V between blend files, so you can do that pretty easy.
